Meromorphic 2-forms on an algebraic surface with prescribed singularity
I am reading Griffiths-Harris's book Principles of Algebraic Geometry. From p.500 to p.505, it is devoted to proof the following lemma:
Let $S$ be a smooth algebraic surface, $C$ be an irreducible curve on $S$, then
$$g(C)\le \pi(C),$$
with equality iff $C$ is smooth.
During the proof, it uses a meromorphic 2-form on $S$ with single poles along $C$ to analyze the difference between the two genera. My question is how to find such a meromorphic 2-form? I think by tensoring with the inverse of a global holomorphic section of $[C]$, a meromorphic 2-form on $S$ with single poles along $C$ is equivalent to a global holomorphic section of $[K_{S}+C]$. Therefore, it is equivalent to the effectiveness of $K_{S}+C$. How can I guarantee this?

Are you talking about a meromorphic $2$-form on $S$ or a holomorphic $2$-form on $S$ (away from $C$)?
